# java- jar file does not run directly in windows, but runs through command prompt

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to run a desktop java app on a Windows 2008 Server based PC.

While I can run the program through command prompt viz. java -jar filename.jar, when I double click on the jar file I get an error message "Could not find the main class. Program will now exit".

I am using Netbeans v7.0.1 on Windows, to develop this application.
Kindly clarify on how to run the app directly on double clicking its icon...

Comment: Post a copy of the jar manifest

Comment: @user974573: Just create run-my-app.cmd with all necessary stuff and run it

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the Main-class in the Manifest.txt file

```
Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass
```

This sets the entry point for the application.

Check out the documentation for more details,

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Netbeans, you need to edit the `manifest.mf` file in the `META-INF` folder  in your .jar archive to point to your `MAIN` class.

If your .jar file is `myjar.jar`, open it up, then open the `manifest.mf` file and edit the `Main-Class` line to point to your main class (the one that contains your main method).

```
Main-Class: mainclass.myjar
```

Save it and run.